# Finding a Prime Numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of length `N=10^5` For each index 1<=i<=n 
I have to calculate the difference between `A[j]-A[i]  and (j-i) is prime and j>i`

Here is my code:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<prime.size();j++){

         int x = prime.get(j);

         if(x+i>n) break;
         ans+= A[x+i]-A[i];
    }
}
```

How should i make this work even faster ? I think the time complexity is **O(N*prime.size)**

Comment: Are you sure there is a faster algorithm?

Comment: What makes you consider the complexity is *not* O(N*prime.size)?

Comment: You seem to be computing a sum; your description says nothing about sums.  In fact, it talks about a difference between an integer and 2 booleans.

Comment: I added [tag:java] language tag. Change it to something appropriate if it's not Java. It's almost always a good idea to add language tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, I will rephrase your question so that it states what I believe you want to achieve. You are probably looking for the sum of the differences of the form `A[j]-A[i]`, where `(j-i)` is a "positive" prime and `1<=i<j<=N`. With this statement in mind...

We count the number of times `A[k]` is added to the sum (denoted by `p`) and the number of times `A[k]` is subtracted from the sum (denoted by `m`). Well, `m` is equal to the number of primes in the interval `[1,N-k]`, while `p` is equal to the number of primes in the interval `[1,k-1]`. If you don't believe me, simulate step-by-step what your code does. Then you can do:

```
S = 0
for k = 1 to N do
    S = S + (p(k) - m(k)) * A[k]
endfor
```

Now, we need to find a way to determine `p` and `m` efficiently for each `k` in the interval `[1,N]`. I see you have already constructed what seems to be an ordered list of primes. So, to answer a query of the form 'how many primes in the interval `[1,t]`?' you could perform a binary search on that list for `t`. This would get the complexity down to `O(N*log(prime.size))`.

As an alternative, you can pre-compute the answers to the queries of the form 'how many primes in the interval `[1,t]`?'. You need an extra array `nrPrimesLessThan` of size `N` to keep the results, doing something like this to compute its values:

```
count = 0
for i = 1 to N do
    if i < prime.get(count) then
        nrPrimesLessThan[i] = count
    else
        count = count + 1
        nrPrimesLessThan[i] = count
    endif
endfor
```

The pre-computation part takes `O(N)` steps, but now one query takes `O(1)` steps, thus the calculating the sum takes `O(N)` steps. Overall, linear time in `N`.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code example, you want to sum the differences of all value pairs in the array for which the difference of the indices is prime. You've got already an array of primes.

The diagram below shows how the elements get subtracted and added:

```
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9

        -       +   +       +       +                0
            -       +   +       +       +            1
                -       +   +       +       +        2
                    -       +   +       +            3
                        -       +   +       +        4
                            -       +   +            5
                                -       +   +        6
                                    -       +        7
                                        -            8
                                            -        9
```

A `+` means an element is added to the overall sum. A `-` means the element is subtracted from the sum. This is not a single subtraction; the subtraction happens for each addition to its left, so `A[0]` is subtracted 4 times. It is never added.

On the other hand, `A[9]` is never subtracted, but added four times. In general, each element is subtracted as many times as there are plusses in a row and it is added as many times as there are plusses in a columns. There is a symmetry here:

```
add[i] = sub[N - i - 1]
```

for zero-based indices. What is the value of `add[i]`? It is the number of primes that are smaller or equal to `i`.

Here's a code example where the `add` array is called `m`:

```
int psum2(const int A[], int n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    int m[n];
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == prime[j]) {
            k++;
            j++;
        }
        m[i] = k;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += (m[i] - m[n - i - 1])  * A[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The array `m` is always the same and can be precalculated if you need to perform the sum more often. The algorithm is O(n).

The problem is also unrelated to primes at its core. The method above works for all conditional sums of differences where the difference of the indices must be conteined in a certain set of numbers.